# Deodhar's inequality: when the equality holds?

Tags: co.combinatorics, inequalities, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system, $T=\bigcup_{w\in W}wSw^{-1}$ and $\ell$ be the length function.

It is well-known that one have the following Deodhar's inequality:

> Let $x\le y\le w$. Then
>   $|\{r\in T: x\le ry\le w\}|\ge \ell(w)-\ell(x)$.

My question is:

> What is the sufficient and necessary condition for the above equality holds?

If the problem is too hard, let us just consider the extreme cases $y=x$ and $y=w$.

For case $y=x$.

> When is $|\{r\in T: x< rx\le w\}|= \ell(w)-\ell(x)$?

This is equivalent to ask

> when is $|\{r\in T: rx\le w\}|= \ell(w)$?

due to the fact that $\ell(x)=|\{r\in T: rx<x\}|$.

For W is a Weyl group, there is a geometry behind: 
[image]

Note that $\Omega_B$ is an open neighbourhood of $e_B$ in $X$.
For more details: Read [**Patrick Polo --- On Zariski tangent spaces of Schubert varieties, and a proof of a conjecture of Deodhar**.](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0019357794900191?token=0F3187EC84B5A8B1A4E3BAA7420BDDD55A2B4F161755D4CCB3B51E1490551FBFDEC46F847F4C1746032D8FE63EFC26DB)

Finally, it is well-known that $\ell(w)=|\{r\in T: rw<w\}|$.

> I would like to know whether $|\{r\in T: rx\le w\}|=\ell(w)\implies |\{r\in T: ry\le w\}|=\ell(w)$ for all $y\in [x,w]$.